# Non awaited task seems to be awaited on. Python Quart

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio, quart

Code below for reference

```
import asyncio
from models import database
from quart import Quart, request, abort, jsonify

app = Quart(__name__)

async def process_input(*args) -> None:
    """ Series of time consuming steps"""
    response = long_request(*args) # Slow, I/O bound
    write_to_database(response) # Fast

@app.route('/query', methods=['POST'])
async def name():
    """ Everything happens really fast here"""        

    arg1, arg2 = some_json_parsing()

    # I want to start this process and immediately move on
    # I don't really think this part is NOT being awaited
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(process_input(arg1,arg2))
    
    # Return a wait message
    data = {...}
    return jsonify(data) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    database.connect()
    database.create_tables([Table]) # If not exists default

    app.run(port=8000)
```

I've tried various permutations of adding `process_input()` into the event loop.

I basically want to start `process_input()` and move on with execution. It takes around 6-7 seconds to execute.

When I try sending requests to the `/query` endpoint with Postman, it takes around 6-7 seconds to return data. All that's happening is reading and writing a json besides attempting to create a task that takes `process_input()` which tells me that for some reason, the `name()` function is probably awaiting `process_input()`.

I'm running the app using uvicorn.

How do I actually achieve my intended behavior ?

Comment: I can assure you that `name()` is not awaiting the completion of `process_input`, unless there is an await expression in the part of the code you did not present.  In fact `process_input` will not begin execution at all, until the thread encounters the first await expression after the call to `create_task`.  You can verify this by inserting print statements in your code.  Your comment indicates that `long_request` is slow, and it's apparently not async because you don't await it.  That will block the event loop.  Perhaps that explains what you're seeing.

Comment: I think a background task is what you need, see these [docs](https://quart.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/how_to_guides/background_tasks.html)